# React Native StackNavigator disappearing on re-entry

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

We are encountering a very bizarre scenario with react-navigation in our React Native application that is only observed on Android (both in the emulator and on physical devices **AND** for debug builds as well as release builds), but it works fine on iOS.

### Context

We have an existing native application, and decided to implement some new screens in React Native as an experiment to see whether it would benefit our development lifecycle.

Our native app has a sidebar menu, and we added a new menu item, that when selected, takes the user into the React Native portion. They can of course navigate back out whenever they want, and later go back into that React Native portion.

### Observed problem (Only occurs in Android)

We have identified it relates to the react-navigation library, but we don't know what we're doing wrong.

When the app is first loaded, the user can select the new menu item and the React Native app loads fine, showing its initial route page and with the StackNavigator working fine.

**If the user returns to the native portion (either via the back key, or by selecting a different option from the sidebarmenu) and then later opts to return to the React Native portion, then the StackNavigator portion doesn't display.** Other React components outside the StackNavigator get rendered. We know it mounts the contained components, as some of them are making API calls and we see those endpoints being queried. It just doesn't render.

Reloading within the emulator will render the app properly again until we navigate out of React Native and then return.

*Oddly enough*: If we turn on remote JS debugging, it suddenly all works fine.

### So our question:

Can anyone spot what we might be missing in how we are using the StackNavigator, that is keeping it from rendering properly? Again: it works fine when the JS debugger is on, making us think that it is not a logic item, but perhaps a timing condition, or some subtle config? Or should we just ditch react-navigation and go to a different navigation library?

### Simple reproduction of the issue

Our package.json is:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.50.4",
    "react-navigation": "1.5.2"
  }
}
```

Our React Native entry page (index.js) is:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import TestPage from './TestPage';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);

class MyApp extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Text>'This text always shows up fine on Android, even on reentry to React application'</Text>
        <AccountNavigator />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const AccountNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    FirstPage: {
      screen: TestPage,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'Test View'
      })
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'FirstPage'
  }
);
```

The simple test page (TestPage.js) is just:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class TestPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text>'If you can read this, then the app is on first load. But return to the native portion and then try to come back to React Native and you will not see me.'</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It does sound like a race condition from what you are describing. But I need to see more code (Some native code that is related to this..) to try and suggest the cause of the issue. Regardless you can try this lib: https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation

Comment: @HedShafran Thank you for the suggestion about react-native-navigation. I had been thinking about that library, so had a look at it last night. From what I can see though, it is aimed purely at iOS and primarily for leveraging iOS tabbed navigation, and the setup documentation seems to support that idea as well.

In my particular case, our issue is with Android, and we're not wanting a tabbed navigation, but a navigation through stacked screens as the user completes forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a layout setting issue. In our native code, within our React Activity layout XML we had:

```
 <com.facebook.react.ReactRootView
    android:id="@+id/ReactRootView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and the issue was in the "wrap_content" for height which was causing it to render the `StackNavigator()` as 1 pixel high. No idea why it always happened only on re-entry and not on the first time, nor why the JS debugger would cause the issue to disappear.

Changing layout_height to "match_parent" resolved the issue altogether.